# Use git via command line

Tags: git, github, cmd

I am having trouble using git via the command line.
I am trying to push up files that change reguarly and may be deleted from my local drive at any point and that would need to be pushed as well.

I know how to do this sort of thing via sourcetree but unsure what to do on the command line

I currently have:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Test"
git remote add *"Repository"*
git push econnectConfig master
```

I want to just basicaly push to the master without any care for what is there but I do not want to use force as I want to see the history of the changes that are made. How do I do this as I a currently getting errors about everything being out of sync.

Cheers

Comment: What's the error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
git init -> initialize a git repository in the current directory
git add --all -> add all files
git commit -m "Test" -> commit which files? git commit -a -m 'test' will add all
git remote add *"Repository"* -> tell you local repository where to connect to
git push econnectConfig master -> push your changes to the remote master branch
```

But your local repository is not aware of the remote contents. So it can not push to it.

Here's one approach:

```
 1.) git fetch -> sync your local with the remote repo 

   2.)  git branch -a -> show all branches: remote and local

   3.)  git checkout master -> checkout the remote master branch to your local repo 

   4.)  git checkout [yourlocalrepo] -> (econnectConfig?) switch to you local branch again

   5.)  git rebase master -> update [yourlocalrepo] to master branch and apply the changes of [yourlocalrepo] on top of them

   6.) git checkout master -> back to your local master branch

   7.) git rebase [yourlocalrepo] -> apply the changes from [yourlocalrepo]  to the master branch

   8.) git push -> push your local changes to the master branch on the remote server
```

If you don't need to push your changes to master you could just push your local branch to a remote one by issuing

```
git push -u origin feature_branch_name
```

If you are not sure what your repositories config is (to averview the remote connections etc pp)

```
git config -l --local (skip the local if you want system wide settings shown)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was very helpful! I found out that the reason what I was doing wasn't working is because my repo was so out of sync and back to front it didn't know what it was doing. With your help and creating a new repo I now have it working. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome!  I always recommend http://gitready.com/ to my coworkers or the tutorials from http://github.com/